# google-pprof show result from ARM

Tags: c++, arm, google-perftools

I'm use google perf tools for analize my program. Run program on arm device Cortex A9.

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libprofiler.so.0" CPUPROFILE=./prof.out CPUPROFILE_REALTIME=1 CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY=1000 TCMALLOC_STACKTRACE_METHOD=arm bin/driver -c etc/driver/config.json
```

Next load profiling result on host linux-mint. And run google-pprof

```
google-pprof --text projects/build/ARM_VARISCITE/bin/driver prof.out
```

But I have corupted results

```
Using local file projects/OrionWebModules/build/ARM_VARISCITE/bin/driver.
Using local file prof.out.
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libPocoXML.so.46': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/librt-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/libdl-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/libpthread-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/libm-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libunwind.so.8.0.1': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/libc-2.19.so':No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/libgcc_s.so.1': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.46': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libPocoJSON.so.46': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libPocoUtil.so.46': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libPocoNet.so.46': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/lib/libprofiler.so.0.4.8': No such file
/usr/bin/objdump: '/lib/ld-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/addr2line: '/lib/ld-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/addr2line: '/usr/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.46':No such file
/usr/bin/addr2line: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18': No such file
/usr/bin/addr2line: '/lib/libc-2.19.so': No such file
/usr/bin/addr2line: '/lib/libpthread-2.19.so': No such file
Total: 202934 samples
202672  99.9%  99.9%   202672  99.9% 76a0d1a4
 212   0.1% 100.0%      212   0.1% 76921c98
  17   0.0% 100.0%       17   0.0% 76a7b774
   6   0.0% 100.0%        6   0.0% 76a9f2fc
   3   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.0% 76aaf474
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76921c9c
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a0d18c
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a0d1b8
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a4ff3c
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a51280
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a539fc
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a57c70
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a9f324
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76a9fba4
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76abd378
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76bc0f20
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76be3308
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76c6fff0
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76d158fc
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76d41a3c
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76f776e8
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76f77ca8
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76f77cb8
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76f7ccd8
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76f86ff0
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% 76f881c0
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% Poco::AtomicCounter::operator--
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% Poco::SharedPtr::release
   1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% __destroy
```

All libraries install in toolchain library. How I can setup sysroot path? And show method names instead of addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need use two flags

first:

```
--tools= /opt/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
```

full path to compiller tools with toolchain prefix. You can use also variable **PPROF_TOOLS**.

second:

```
--lib_prefix=<path_to_usr_lib>,<path_toolchain_lib>
```

also need disable gcc flag -fomit-frame-pointer